# JQuery DataTables: adjust column size without redrawing the table and making a new ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, datatables

I am using the jquery datatables plugin on a project using server side processing to populate the data table ( using servlets ). I am also using jquery ui layout plugin so I am trying to tie resizing of a pane to readjust the column sizing of the table on call back. This is working but when I check firebug I see that each call to fnAdjustColumnSizing is calling my ajax servlet. I assume this is through calling the fnDraw method but I am not certain. Is there a way to get it to readjust without making a new ajax call?

I am paginating literally hundreds of thousands of rows if the user decides to so recalling the servlet for this purpose is possibly a big waste of time for the user. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

http://datatables.net/ref#fnAdjustColumnSizing - you can pass false as the first parameter to stop it redrawing, but the new sizes wouldn't be taking into effect until a draw is done... There are ways you can do this (calling the internal functions such as _fnScrollDraw) however:

Are you passing back hundreds of thousands of rows every time? With server-side processing (which I presume is what you are using) you only need to return the rows that are to be displayed.

Comment: No i returning the number of rows in the page size. I will try passing in false. Hopefully this works as what I am actually trying to avoid is the added ajax call just to relayout the table. Thanks alot for the tip. Check back in after I try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add nowrap attribute to td tag, so its adjust width of your data, you can try something like these :-

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap="nowrap"></td>
    </td>
</table>
```